# How to turn off prompt when using new-psdrive remotely?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

This is my script:

```
New-PSDrive -name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\files\Applications -Credential `$cred
```

But it prompts me when I run it remotely using `invoke-command`, asking me to confirm the creation of `J`. How can I turn this prompt off? The credentials are for an administrator user.

Comment: Have you tried using `-Confirm:$false`?

Comment: This didn't work. I ended up giving up on this and using invoke-webrequest to get the file from a  url.